# Replacement for AppDomain.GetLoadedAssemblies() in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to write some logic to mirror some existing logic in an original .NET application. In my `OnModelCreating()` method I want to load all current types in loaded assemblies to find the ones that need to be registered for entity type configuration in the model.

This was done in .NET with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => a.GetTypes())`, however `AppDomain` no longer exists in .NET Core.

Is there a new way to do this?

I have seen some examples online of using `DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries` however `DependencyContext.Default` does not seem to exist anymore either.

**Edit:**

I have found now that adding `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` to a `.netcoreapp1.1` project works. However I am actually writing a solution with multiple projects and I somehow need do this type loading in my `.netstandard1.4` project where my DbContext implementation and entity type configuration is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed this by upgrading my `.netstandard` projects from `1.4` to `1.6`. The package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 1.1.2` now works.

**Edit:**

Using `.netstandard2.0` removes the need for an `AppDomain` polyfill class since it contains many more .NET APIs including `System.AppDomain`

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is broadly explained [here](http://www.michael-whelan.net/replacing-appdomain-in-dotnet-core/). The author recommends creating a polyfill.

I am going to copy and paste in case the page goes missing.

```
public class AppDomain
{
    public static AppDomain CurrentDomain { get; private set; }

    static AppDomain()
    {
        CurrentDomain = new AppDomain();
    }

    public Assembly[] GetAssemblies()
    {
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        var dependencies = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries;
        foreach (var library in dependencies)
        {
            if (IsCandidateCompilationLibrary(library))
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(library.Name));
                assemblies.Add(assembly);
            }
        }
        return assemblies.ToArray();
    }

    private static bool IsCandidateCompilationLibrary(RuntimeLibrary compilationLibrary)
    {
        return compilationLibrary.Name == ("Specify")
            || compilationLibrary.Dependencies.Any(d => d.Name.StartsWith("Specify"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen something along these lines in a blog post, however I have added the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` package  but `DependencyContext.Default` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @m.brookson I just created .net core 1.1 application with DependencyModel (version 1.1.2) and it works perfectly.
In addition dependences that may be (or not) related: 
`Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 1.1.2,
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 1.1.2,
Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1,
System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives 4.1.1`

Comment: I'm actually trying to implement this in a .netstandard1.4 class library project which is referenced by a .netcoreapp1.1 web application. Will that make a difference?

Comment: @m.brookson Sadly, I have no idea

Comment: Just added `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` to the `.netcoreapp1.1` and it works there! Somehow need to use the values in my `.netstandard1.4` project. Hm...

Comment: Fixed this by upgrading my `.netstandard` projects from `1.4` to `1.6`. The package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 1.1.2` now works.